# shell script error when declaring command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

Code below is supposed to check the memory for user and if its greater than 1000, print message
I keep getting error- line 4: impala: command not found

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ true ] ;do
used= `ps hax -o rss,user | awk '{a[$2]+=$1;}END{for(i in a)print i" 
"int(a[i]/1024+0.5);}' | grep user`

if [[ $used > 1000 ]]; then
echo "user memory is $used"

fi
sleep 5
done
```

I have tried used= `ps hax -o rss,user | awk '{a[$2]+=$1;}END{for(i in a)print i" "int(a[i]/1024+0.5);} | grep user'`

and used= `'ps hax -o rss,user | awk '{a[$2]+=$1;}END{for(i in a)print i" "int(a[i]/1024+0.5);}' | grep user'`
I need a fresh eye on this. Please help.

Comment: remove the space

Comment: Remove the space after the equals sign?

Comment: Jesus.. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bash, as mentioned [[ **here** ]](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_02.html#sect_03_02_02), putting spaces around the equal sign would cause errors, So the right format is

```
variable_name=value;
```

Moreover, you may change

```
while [ true ]
```

to

```
while true
```

**Edit**

If `used` has the form `impala 600` and you're only interested in the number at the end, then you may do

```
used="${used##* }"
#Do this just after the your first command.
```

Finally do

```
#use -gt for integer comparisons and > for string comparisons
if ! [ -t $used ] && [ $used -gt 1000 ]
then
  echo "user memory is $used"
fi
```

<sup>**Note:** Though the syntax errors in the script is resolved there is no guarantee that the program logic is right</sup>

Comment: my output from ps hax -o rss,user | awk '{a[$2]+=$1;}END{for(i in a)print i" "int(a[i]/1024+0.5);}' | grep impala is impala 600. Im trying to remove "impala" Ive tried ps hax -o rss,user | awk '{a[$2]+=$1;}END{for(i in a)print i" "int(a[i]/1024+0.5);}' | grep impala | sed 's/\D+/g' <<< "$s" with no luck

Comment: Thank you. another thing is im still getting output when I shouldnt. since 600 is not > 1000